# Java: call .bat and redirect its output

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a Java-GUI for a number of Windows system calls.
I generate the needed calls from templates and write them to a .bat file to separate debugging the command creation from debugging the command effects.

I then run the generated batch file with following code:

```
int executeCommand(String[] cmd) {
        String cmd_full = "";
        // here: concat and format the string array for logging only
        try {
            log.println( "executing: " + cmd_full );
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd, null, new File( workDir + "/" ) );
            String line;
            BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p.getInputStream() ) );
            while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
                log.println( "> " + line );
            }
            p.waitFor();
            bri.close();
            return p.exitValue();
        } catch (Exception e) { // simplified
            log.println( "Windows error occured" );
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

(log is a global `PrintWriter` and workDir a globalString) This executes commands as desired. If I pass commands and arguments directly, the output is written to the logger, but when I call the batch file by

```
executeCommand( new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "start", "generated.bat" } )
```

it won't redirect the output properly, although the batch gets run.

I don't know much about Windows or the interaction of Java, batch-files and the OS layer, so I have no idea where the problem is. Is it a simple reordering of commands, like `p.waitFor()` before printing? But then I'd run into problems with the buffer's size limit I guess, although I might try this out right away.

Any help or clues appreciated.

Comment: if you pass the command and arguments directly as one single string and it works fine, then it should also work with the array of String..
Have you checked the way your `log.println()` works?
some kind of writing permission/access issue, perhaps?

Comment: `"start"` will execute its argument in another console; this is probably why you are not getting the actual output. Do you really need `start`?